# zope_i18n_compile_mo_files doesn't work on a Zeo configuration

Tags: plone, zope

I'm in trouble with the "local translation" override by buildout configuration. I would like to override some standard labels of plone using the extra conf parameter "zope_i18n_compile_mo_files" with a folder placed in the buildout's directory (plone 4.3) : "locales/it/LC_MESSAGES/plone.po"
In another Plone 4.1 installation it works well. The only difference between these installations are the plone version (4.1 vs 4.3) and the architecture (stand alone vs zeo cluster).

This is the piece of my buildout:

```
[instance-settings]
user = admin:admin
debug-mode = off
verbose-security = off
blob-storage = ${buildout:directory}/var/blobstorage
effective-user = ${config:system-user}
products = ${buildout:directory}/products
eggs =
    ${plone:eggs}
zcml =
    ${plone:zcml}
resources = ${buildout:directory}/resources
environment-vars =
    PTS_LANGUAGES it en
    LANG it_IT.utf8
    TZ Europe/Rome
    zope_i18n_allowed_languages it en
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that:

a) .po files contains no error? Try to manually compile it -

b) the env var is really passed to instance definition? Maybe you override it somewhere (so you have a configuration error). The simple way to check it is to see inside the `parts/instancexxx/etco/zope.conf`

Comment: I believe that newer versions of Plone UnifiedInstaller set this flag by default, and that it's no longer required for end-users to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register that locales directory.  I do not see that in your buildout config.  Something like this:

`[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
locales = ${buildout:directory}/locales`

See https://github.com/mauritsvanrees/maurits.i18ntalk/blob/master/talk.rst#buildoutcfg