# How to debug Zope's translation machinery in Plone

Tags: localization, internationalization, overriding, plone, zope

I have a Plone 4.3 add-on that sets a site and installs some dependencies using its own buildout configuration, in which I need to localize some Plone translations.

I'm using a distributed configuration with a ZEO server and 2 ZEO clients running multiple Plone instances.

I have tried everything recommended in other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735367/zope-i18n-compile-mo-files-doesnt-work-on-a-zeo-configuration), [blog posts](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/10/i18n-plone-4) and [presentations](https://github.com/mauritsvanrees/maurits.i18ntalk/blob/master/talk.rst#buildoutcfg) without luck:

- adding my overriding translations to the `plone` domain inside my add-on own `locales` folder, declaring it in the `configure.zcml` file
- adding my overriding translations to the `plone` domain inside a buildout `locales` folder, declaring it in the `buildout.cfg` file

I added the following to my buildout configuration and I see the .mo files being created when I start my instances:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
environment-vars =
    PTS_LANGUAGES en, es, pt-br
    zope_i18n_allowed_languages en, es, pt_BR
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
zcml = my.addon
```

Other translations are working fine; the only one that is failing came from [one template that is overridden in one of the add-ons](https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf/blob/master/src/collective/nitf/browser/configure.zcml#L52:L59) (specifically, the [label_filed_under](https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf/blob/master/src/collective/nitf/browser/templates/keywords.pt#L6) name in the template).

What I'm doing wrong? How can I debug this?

Comment: Hi Hector, I guess this Plone 4.3, right ? If you added zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true, did you check that the po file has been compiled to a mo file ?

Comment: thanks, @godefroid-chapelle, I updated my question according with yours; maybe the commas?

Comment: You did not tell if the mo files have been added besides your po file after having started your instance...

Comment: yes, it's in the edit; but, yes, they are being created.

Comment: A) a common mistake is to forget to register the locales directory in your package's configure.zcml: `<i18n:registerTranslations directory="locales" />`

B) did you place your po file in `your.package/locales/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/plone.po`?

C) it could be, that the order in which your packages are loaded matters. try
[instance]
zcml=package.to.override your.package

Comment: I haven't seen a buildout level locales folder. I'd remove that, but keep if course the compile option. Did you include the package, which you want to override, in your zcml on top? You have to make sure it's loaded before your own locales.

Comment: I have added more information to the question: the translation that fails is one from an overridden template.

Comment: Did you check namespacing issue ? More specifically, what I consider to be a bug documented in the following test : https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.tal/blob/master/src/zope/tal/tests/test_talinterpreter.py#L555

Comment: seems the problem could be produced by a worng order in some ZCML directives; I haven't tested yet in that project: https://github.com/plone/bobtemplates.plone/issues/110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific issue was caused by a very simple problem: I forgot to add the `i18n` name space declaration to the template:

```xml
<html
    ...
    xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
    ...
    >
```

A coworker discovered that here after taking a look.

That's why is important to do code reviewing always.